# Разделить список на равные части в C#

Tags: c#, list

Столкнулся с проблемой, что в списке данные указаны подряд, нужно разделить список по 4 элемента, дано:

```
{"autor", "name", "date", "publisher", "autor", "name", "date", "publisher", "autor", "name", "date", "publisher"}
```

вот что должно получиться в итоге:

```
{{"autor", "name", "date", "publisher"}, {"autor", "name", "date", "publisher"}, {"autor", "name", "date", "publisher"}}
```

заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Т. е. по 4 разбить или что? Напишите полные правила

Comment: да, нужно разбить список по 4 элемента

Answer (score 1):

Под текст разделить я понял выводить в консоль раздельным видом.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Script
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> JustAList = new List<string> { "autor", "name", "date", "publisher", "autor", "name", "date", "publisher", "autor", "name", "date", "publisher" };
        static int PartsCount = 4;

        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < JustAList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{JustAList[i]} ");
                if (i % PartsCount == PartsCount - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выглядит вот так.

[image]